# Convert Python Hash method to PHP

Tags: python, php

I'm currently trying to convert a Python hash method to PHP.

Python:
`password = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha1(user_password.encode('ascii')).digest()).decode("utf-8")`

PHP: `password = base64_encode(openssl_digest(sha1(ord($user_password)), "sha256"));`

Can someone help? :)

Comment: SHA-1 you can have easier than by invoking openssl functionality, with just https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php

Comment: `ord($user_password)` probably makes rather little sense, because that _"[i]nterprets the binary value of the first byte of character as an unsigned integer between 0 and 255." - and I doubt that is what `user_password.encode('ascii')` does.

Comment: And the equivalent for the `.decode("utf-8")` appears to be missing in your PHP attempt.

Comment: @CBroe There is no equivalent to `bytes.decode` in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent PHP code is:

```
base64_encode(sha1($user_password, true))
```

In detail:

- `user_password.encode('ascii')` has no equivalent, as PHP only has byte arrays as string type which cannot be encoded or decoded to/from another string type.
- `hashlib.sha1(...).digest()` is equivalent to `sha1(..., true)`. Just `sha1(...)` is equivalent to `hashlib.sha1(...).hexdigest()`. `digest` has nothing to do with `openssl_digest`; it just gives you the current hash digest value. Contrary to PHP, you can successively update a hash in Python and thus need an explicit "end" somewhere. In PHP you can only feed one value in and get one value out.
- `base64.b64encode(...).decode("utf-8")` is simply `base64_encode` to encode the raw bytes returned by the SHA1 hash to base 64. Again, there's no equivalent to `decode`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sometimes you just overthink stuff even tho it's a lot more simple.